# How to force curl to wait

Tags: php, curl, timing

I'm working on a university economics project and I'm trying to gather a small amount of data from each of many sources.  My code looks like:

```
<?php
$ca = curl_init ("http://www.website.com/page.aspx?part1=1&part2=2");
curl_setopt ($ca, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec ($ca);
echo $data;
?>
```

It works for some sites and fails on others.  The problem is that the curl doesn't "wait" for the page to finish loading in some instances.  These pages act kind of like kayak.com, where the page updates over time and then after a while it's finished.  How can I make curl wait for this kind of thing to end?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error message from CURL, or does CURL return the page but without the specific information you were hoping to find on the page?

Comment: it returns the page, but where there would be a table of information it's just not there.  It's as if I went to the website, loaded the page, and then somehow stopped it from finishing loading.

Comment: You're probably forgetting that most websites these days are not static documents. There's probably a huge amount of JavaScript which pulls data into the page, and CURL will not be able to run that JavaScript no matter what delay you give it. Usually the only realistic way to get such data is to use static XML feeds. If the site does not offer data in feed form, you could contact the site operator and say that you need it for a limited time for a university project.